# MEAN Stack routing misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am creating a League of Legends website with Riot's Developer API.

I know how to setup routing and what not but I am confused about something, which pages/urls are handled by express routing and which pages/urls are handled by angular? Can somebody please help me with an example? I've been at this for a couple weeks now and no luck.
so i'll have like website.com/player/playerName will search riot's developer api by that players name and pull up stats for that page.

appreciate any help I can get

Comment: There are lots of different MEAN scaffold projects that you can install , usually with Yoeman, that will provide simple working app you can use to reference

Comment: They both can. You choose which ones are handled.

Answer (score 0):

Express will handle the server side routing, Angular will handle any client side routing.

Server side routing uses the server side compiler to generate the web page, the web page code is then sent to the browser to render. This happens when the server (Express/Node) receives a request, this usually passes through your index.js (in routes dir) or routes.js where you have some code to route that request:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('root');
});
```

You can learn more about Express routing here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Client side routing is using Javascript to change the already rendered code which is now loaded in the browser. So all of this routing is taking place in the browser. Angular uses templates in its routing system, so you can load a different template as the user navigates without forcing the browser to load a new page. You angular routing would be in your app.js in a public directory, and the routing code would look something like this:

```
angular.module('pathApp',[] ,function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/Book/Delete', {
    template: '<div class="box" ng-class="classname">Delete</div>',
    controller: function($scope) {$scope.classname="delete"}
  })
  .when('/Book/Show', {
    template: '<div class="box" ng-class="classname">Show</div>',
    controller: function($scope) {$scope.classname="show"}
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/Book/Error'});
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);        
});
```

You can learn more about angular routing here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route